# How to Print output of shell script in different columns of csv file

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have written a shell script and want to print output of 5 defined variables in csv file, I am using a condition, If condition 1 success then output should print in first 5 columns, else output should in next 5 columns, like below:

`if condition 1 success`

```
$DAY,$ModName,$Version,$END_TIME,$START_TIME
```

(should print in column number 1..5 of csv)

`if condition 2 success`

```
$DAY,$ModName,$Version,$END_TIME,$START_TIME
```

(should print in column number 6..10 of csv)

But using my code output always appends to next row

Below is my code:

```
if [ "$Version" = linux ] 
then 
echo "$DAY","$ModName","$Version","$END_TIME","$START_TIME" | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $a ","}' >> output.csv;
else 
echo "$DAY","$ModName","$Version","$END_TIME","$START_TIME" | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $b}' >> output.csv; 
fi
```

I tried n number of things apart from this code, but not able to find the solution.

I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: For instance: You are using awk variables `a` and `b`, but you never assign a value to them.

Comment: @user1934428, I tried doing awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5} , It works for 1st  5 values which satisfies with 1st condition, but applying awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $6, $7, $8, $9, $10} is not printing values in column 6...10 .

Comment: You have only 5 input fields, so $6 will always be empty.

Comment: @user1934428 , I know, this is where i am stuck with, do you have any suggestion for this, so that i can drive in right direction ?

Comment: Why? You already received a complete answer to your question by Walter A.

Comment: @user1934428, by using Walter's approach, I can print the values in 6..10 rows, but my question is how can i print the values in 6..10 columns

Comment: He doesn't print in separate rows. Please update your posting by your complete program based on Walter's solution, so we can't investigate.

Answer (score 1):

`{print $6, $7, $8, $9, $10}` refers to input fields, not output.
When you want to start with 5 empty fields just printf them (avoiding a `\n`)

```
if [ "${Version}" != "linux" ]; then 
   printf "%s" ",,,,,"
fi
echo "${DAY},${ModName},${Version},${END_TIME},${START_TIME}"
```

(Next time please use lowercase variable names)

When a variable can have a ',', you might need to give values in double quotes.

Comment: your answer didn't help me out.